# StackOverflowException when changing DataGridViewButtonCell value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button, datagridview

I am developing a Windows Forms application which uses a `DataGridView` control. This `DataGridView` has a cell that contains a button. The default button text is `Start` but when I try to change it dynamically like:

```
((DataGridViewButtonCell)Myrow.Cells[9]).Value = "End";
```

or simply like

```
Myrow.Cells[9].Value = "End";
```

It throws following exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

My complete code is like this:

```
void HighlightOnlineUsers()
{
     foreach (DataGridViewRow Myrow in dataGridView1.Rows)
     {
             if (Convert.ToInt32(Myrow.Cells[8].Value) > 0)
             {
                  Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
                  Myrow.Cells[9].Value = "End";
             }
             else {
                  Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                  ((DataGridViewButtonCell)Myrow.Cells["SessionAction"]).Value = "Start";
             }
     }
}
```

Comment: The question is where do you call `HighlightOnlineUsers` from

Comment: @IvanStoev it's in the code file of the `Form` in which `DataGridView` is situated.

Comment: I mean, looks like you are calling it from some event, and the implementation triggers the same event, hence StackOverflowException.

Comment: @IvanStoev I am calling it from `dataGridView1_CellFormatting` event. And also from other events too that changes data.

Comment: That's what causing the  exception, `dataGridView1_CellFormatting` event triggered for every format update, this makes recursive as you are updating `CellFormat` in this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have different text for buttons, you can handle [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event of your grid and put the logic for formatting value of the column there.

```
private void grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    //If this is header row or new row, do nothing
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == this.grid.NewRowIndex)
        return;

    //I suppose your button is at index 9
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 9)
    {
        //You can put your dynamic logic here
        //and use different values based on other cell values
        //for example based on cell at index 8      
        if (Convert.ToInt32(this.grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value) > 0)
            e.Value = "End";
        else
            e.Value = "Start";
    }
}
```

You should assign this handler to `CellFormating` event:

```
this.grid.CellFormatting += grid_CellFormatting;
```

Comment: That's working. But I may also want to call this from `dataGridView1_Sorted` event. How can I do that?

Comment: I think it's enough to have such code in cell formatting event. If you need a specific requirement for sort or something else, feel free to ask another question and I as other community members will try to help you to solve the problem. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will ask another question if formatting during sorting doesn't work properly. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Buttons"].Value = "some value";
}
```

Note `"Buttons"` is the name of the column

Comment: How it is different from my approach?